# Extract object from a modified string

Tags: javascript

I am getting an object by name response, which has a property by name attribute_dim.

On hovering on

```
response.attribute_dim
```

I see

```
"{"Coupon Circle":"coupon_circle"}"
```

in chrome developer tools.(see Image)

[image]

On doing below

```
JSON.parse(response.attributes_dim);
```

I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

What should I do in order to get the object out of it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `JSON.parse(response.attributes_dim)` as in your screenshot?

Comment: are you trying to get `JSON.parse(response.attributes_dim);` maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I named it wrongly, the property name is attributes_dim

Comment: When I do, JSON.parse("{"Coupon Circle":"coupon_circle"}"), I get error because of double quotes.

Comment: @Mozak that's just the way strings are shown in the debugger. `JSON.parse('{"Coupon Circle":"coupon_circle"}')` works fine. Can you put `console.log(a)` immediately after the highlighted line and **copy** and **paste** the console output directly into your question above?

Comment: ok, let me try that and see if it throws any error on console.

Answer (score 0):

Your response has `attributes_dim`  as property not `attributes`.

So you need to call JSON parser in this way:

```
JSON.parse(response.attributes_dim);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be a typo from your end.
Use:

JSON.parse(response.attributes_dim);